# Crash on search with quote character

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I have a search field and the text is fired against CoreData using:

```
produkt.name CONTAINS[cd] %@
```

but this crashes when the user types `'`, because the `'` character messes up my query:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception NSInvalidArgumentException
>   Reason: Unable to parse the format string produkt.name CONTAINS[cd].

Isn't there an option in CoreData to handle that? I can't imagine that I have to escape it by myself?

Comment: It should be no problem to search for `'`. Please show the code how you create the predicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think ,it will take care of that .

below is what i tried is and passed **Oh ' gd "** as string in search Box.

```
- (void) stringWithPredicateText : (NSString *)predicateText {

    if ([predicateText length] >0) {
        NSLog(@"predicateText = (%@)",predicateText);
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"location contains[cd] %@",predicateText];
        NSLog(@"Predicate = <%@>",predicate);
    }   

}
```

output :

Test[52856:707] predicateText = (Oh ' gd ")

Test[52856:707] Predicate = (location CONTAINS[cd] "Oh ' gd \"")

Here You can see predicate text and Predicate are correctly formed, its already taking care of ' and " character , and my app does not crash .

Answer (score 2):

You should not have to do any substitution of characters whatsoever.  I'm guessing that you're creating your predicate like this:

```
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"produkt.name CONTAINS[cd] '%@'", term];
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:s];
```

That would be incorrect.  All you need to do is this:

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"produkt.name CONTAINS[cd] %@", term];
```

That will work regardless of any single quotes, etc in the search term.

Comment: Unable to parse the format string "(nachname CONTAINS[cd] 'M) OR (vorname CONTAINS[cd] 'M)"' was created by [subString appendFormat:@"(%@ CONTAINS[cd] %@) OR ", columns[i],phrase];
            }
            else{
                [subString appendFormat:@"(%@ CONTAINS[cd] %@)", columns[i],phrase];

Comment: @netshark1000 please post your predicate creation code in the question. Appending formats like you're doing is the cause of your troubles, and if you post the code I can show you how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace that string `'` with string `''`, like

```
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"''"];
```

Answer (score -1):

If you do not need to search for the `'` character, you can simply exclude it from the search field in your text field delegate callback:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField 
     shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range 
     replacementString:(NSString *)string {

   if ([string isEqualToString:@"'"]) return NO;
   return YES;
}
```

You could also remove the offending character directly when constructing the predicate.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"produkt.name CONTAINS[cd] %@",
  [searchString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@""]];
```

Comment: and what if the user should be able to search for '?

Comment: According to your question, it is not.